# Errorbars in gnuplot change the location of my points

Tags: gnuplot, errorbar

My graph originally look like this:

[without errorbars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3DbZ.png)

But with error bars i get something like this:

[with errorbars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbiMl.png)

This clearly isn't the same graph while in my description I just simply added "with errorbars".

My code is following :

```
plot "m20gnu.txt" using 1:2 title"Massa 20 g" pt 1 ps 0.8 lt 9,f(x) title  "Best passende rechte bij massa 20 g"
```

and `with errorbars`:

```
plot "m20gnu.txt" using 1:2 title"Massa 20 g" with errorbars pt 1 ps 0.8 lt 9,f(x) title  "Best passende rechte bij massa 20 g"
```

The data file looks like this:

```
0.16975     0.058823529     0.005   1

0.165       0.061728395     0.005   1

0.1415      0.047169811     0.005   1

0.13825     0.048543689     0.005   1

0.13975     0.045454545     0.005   1

0.1265      0.054945055     0.005   1

0.146791667 0.052083333     0.005   1
```

Does someone know what goes wrong here ? 
Thanks a lot already

Comment: How should we be able to help you if you don't even show you `plot` command? Have in mind, that you must provide more data column when plotting with error bars, so you must also adapt your `using` part

Comment: I changed it, I am sorry if it wasn't enough information I am very new at this and have  no clue what can be useful and what isn't

Comment: Honestly no clue sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When plotting without errorbars, you have `using 1:2`, which  means: use the first column as x, and the second column as y value.

Now, plotting `with errorbars` requires three values. So by using the same `using` statement again, you are missing one value. Depending on the selected plotting style, gnuplot tries to guess the third value, if you don't specify all. The documentation for `yerrorbars` says:

```
2 columns: [implicit x] y ydelta
3 columns: x y ydelta
4 columns: x y ylow yhigh
```

In your case

```
plot "m20gnu.txt" using 1:2:3 with errorbars
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot this works perfectly. Could you just explain what I have to do if I want x errorbars too

Comment: Then  you must plot `with xyerrorbars`, usually with four columns.

Comment: which one i place in 3th and 4th column? y in 3th and x in 4th ?

Comment: Probably `dx` in 3rd, and `dy` in 4th, see the docs for details.